# Mulesoft project to react

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs, mule

Okay so i am very new to the whole mulesoft thing. what i am currently doing is that i got an mulesoft flow that first authorize me to Linkedin then get my basic profile details. what i know want to do is display that information in my React mockup, how do i get the json result from my mulesoft flow into my React app and display it?

here is my mulesoft flow

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xmlns:tcp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:oauth2="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:linkedin="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/linkedin" xmlns:barn1="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/barn1" xmlns:barn="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/barn" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/linkedin http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/linkedin/current/mule-linkedin.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2/current/mule-oauth2.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp/current/mule-tcp.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="3000" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" connectionIdleTimeout="3000000"/>
    <http:request-config name="AcceptHTTP_Request_Configuration" host="api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?" port="403" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"  connectionIdleTimeout="300000000" protocol="HTTPS">
        <oauth2:authorization-code-grant-type clientId="77ii50ttcezoti" clientSecret="aifsEkcXEiMsayru" redirectionUrl="http://localhost:3000/callback">
            <oauth2:authorization-request authorizationUrl="https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&amp;state=987654321" localAuthorizationUrl="http://localhost:3000/authorize"/>
            <oauth2:token-request tokenUrl="http://linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken" >
                <oauth2:token-response >
                    <oauth2:custom-parameter-extractor paramName="token_1" value="#[json:token_type]"/>
                </oauth2:token-response>
            </oauth2:token-request>
        </oauth2:authorization-code-grant-type>
    </http:request-config>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="api.linkedin.com" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <oauth2:token-manager-config name="Token_Manager_Config" doc:name="Token Manager Config"/>
    <flow name="testingFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/linkedin" doc:name="authorize" allowedMethods="GET"/>
        <http:request config-ref="AcceptHTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="GET" doc:name="getaccesstoken"/>
        <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Be careful: your are sharing your clientId and clientSecret which are sensitive that allow you to be authentified in LinkedIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, You have got the linkedin profile information.
Now in mule the information will be available as payload, you can access it by #[payload] and will be available as response. To access this in any frontend technology(react,angular, backbone) just call the respective mule flow.

In your case : localhost:3000/linkedin (call as GET)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your profile information as a payload the Mule API after that you can need to test your API with postman

If every think is working well, you will need to create the same request with your frontend technologie (React, Angular, VueJs...)